# Non static variable and static function in calling jsp

Tags: java, jsp, rest, static

I am trying to call the restful web service written in java from the JSP page.

I have simple rest web service which returns the same post data sent by the JSP page.
For sending the post data, I have declared the string in jsp and want to access that in the function(API) to send the post data to the web service.

My JSP page is

```
<%! static public String input = "hello";%>
<%
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource service = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/ITHelpdesk/webresources/hello.viewinfo");

ClientResponse cliresponse = WebResource.type("text/html").post(ClientResponse.class,input);

%>
```

I get the error at line

```
 ClientResponse cliresponse = WebResource.type("text/html").post(ClientResponse.class,input);
```

How should I handle the non static variable in the non-static functions.

Comment: Why use a `static` variable in JSP ?

Comment: In fact, why use scriplets in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've *got* a `WebResource` reference already, stored in your `service` variable. You're then ignoring it. I suspect you just want:

```
ClientResponse cliresponse = service.type("text/html")
                                    .post(ClientResponse.class,input);
```